# How do I combine two different meshs in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Due to technical issues, I decided to merge the teeth and gums together into one to make it easier to animate but when I move them in edit mode, both the meshs started turning in their own positions. Is there a way to combine them or a least make them move together without having one or the other move out of position? *Had to edit this because it turns out I forgot to join the two objects together also the red circle is the teeth, and the blue circle is the gums.*[image][image]

Comment: You still have two seperate meshes with different origin points as you can see from the orange dots. Depending on how you have the pivot point set, each mesh will rotate relative to its own origin point.

Comment: @Stephen How did you accomplish this: "I decided to merge the teeth and gums together into one"? From the screenshot you show, it does not look like you merged them at all. you just selected both objects and went into *Edit Mode*. That doesn't make them "Merged"

Comment: It also helps us when you give a screenshot of the full Blender interface. This shows us what you are doing in other sections, gives us a few more clues on what the problem might be so we can better help you :)

Comment: From your updated question, to merge them into one object, Shift-select both in object Mode and then use Ctrl-J. Both will be merged into one object under the name of the one that was selected last.